# Odd bug in C#4 compiler? Alias namespaces getting mixed up

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, alias

Here's my issue,

I'm using a namespace to remove ambiguity from a factory class which is creating domain objects from entity framework entity objects (a POCO factory,.. if that makes sense!). Call me old fashioned but I like things this way :-)

The namespaces I'm working with are aliased as such -

```
using Entities = DataAccess.Models.AccessControl;
using Cases = DomainModel.BusinessObjects.Implimentations.Cases;
```

Now, the `DomainModel.BusinessObjects.Implimentations.Cases` namespace only has one type so far called `CaseType`. However whilst I was working on another type which consumes the `CaseType` class I noticed that when I 'dot' into the `Cases` alias, it points to a totally different namespace in my `DataAccess` assembly and gives me the `CaseTypeFactory` in intellisense.

[image]

So I checked the `CaseType` and `CaseTypeFactory` classes and they are namespaced correctly.  What in god's name is going on?  I really can't work this one out.

Here's the code for the `CaseType` and `CaseTypeFactory` if it helps.

**CaseTypeFactory**

```
using Domain = DomainModel.BusinessObjects.Implimentations.Cases;
using Entities = DataAccess.Models.AccessControl;
using Interfaces.DataAccess;

    namespace DataAccess.Factories.Cases
    {
        public class CaseTypeFactory :
            IEntityPOCOFactory<Domain.CaseType, Entities.CaseType>
        {
            #region IEntityPOCOFactory<CaseType,CaseType> Members

            public Domain.CaseType CreatePOCO(Entities.CaseType entity)
            {
                return new Domain.CaseType(entity.Id, entity.Name, entity.LastChanged);
            }

            public IList<Domain.CaseType> CreatePOCOs(
                IEnumerable<Entities.CaseType> entities)
            {
                var toReturn = new List<Domain.CaseType>();

                foreach (var entity in entities)
                {
                    toReturn.Add(CreatePOCO(entity));
                }
                return toReturn;
            }

            #endregion
        }
    }
```

**CaseType**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using DomainModel.BusinessObjects.Base;

namespace DomainModel.BusinessObjects.Implimentations.Cases
{
    public class CaseType : NamedNumberedAndVersioned
    {
        public CaseType(string name, DateTime lastChanged)
            : this(0, name, lastChanged) { }

        public CaseType(int id, string name, DateTime lastChanged)
            : base(id, name, lastChanged) { }

        public void Update(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

It's probably worth mentioning I'm working with .Net 4.0 / VS2010

**Any** help would be massively appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the code you're writing in the `DataAccess.Factories` namespace? If so, then `Cases` will indeed resolve to `DataAccess.Factories.Cases` first.

Two options:

- Use an alias which *isn't* also the name of another namespace, e.g.

  ```
  using DomainCases = ...
  ```
- Use `::` instead of `.` to force it to use the alias:

  ```
  IEntityPOCOFactory<Cases::CaseType, Whatever>
  ```

I'd personally go for the first option to make things clearer... or try to avoid requiring namespace aliases to start with.

Comment: How very strange.  You are, as always, right on the money.  Why when I've qualified the namespace the alias should use does it have to 'resolve' at all?  Peculiar but thanks very much Jon.

Comment: @Stimul8d: Well, because you can *also* use the dot notation with non-aliases (whereas :: will *only* work with aliases). When in doubt, try to give a name only one meaning :)